# How to parse JSON properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got problem parse JSON data in proper format. This is my JSON data. I just want to grab `beneAcctNumber` from the data:

```
{
"restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts": {
        "101010-BPD Bali-Permata ALTO": {
            "beneficiaryNote": null,
            "beneficiaryName": "Permata ALTO",
            "accountCurrency": "IDR",
            "paymentType": null,
            "beneficiaryIdType": null,
            "transferLimit": null,
            "beneficiaryResident": null,
            "accountLimit": 5.0E7,
            "bankName": "BPD Bali",
            "lastModTime": null,
            "ibInterAcctRef": null,
            "bankCode": "000129",
            "beneficiaryEmail": null,
            "ibInterAcctStrcol1": null,
            "ibInterAcctStrcol2": null,
            "userId": 1551,
            "beneAcctNumber": "101010",
            "beneficiaryId": null,
            "mobileNumber": null
        }
    },
}
```

I got undefined value after retrieved it. My attempt for this one:

```
restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts[0].beneAcctNumber
```

Comment: what is the parent main node?

Comment: restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts only

Comment: `beneAcctNumber` is a property of the object referenced by the property `101010-BPD Bali-Permata ALTO`. You're trying to access this last one as it was an array. Try `restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts['101010-BPD Bali-Permata ALTO'].beneAcctNumber`. Note: I'm using the square brakets because that property key has white spaces in it.

Comment: is it a best practice using string instead numeric value? just asking

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I already found the correct answer. 100% working.

```
var output = "";
$.each(restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts, function(index, item) {
    output += item.beneAcctNumber ;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts is not an array, so [0] is undefined...
something like this would do it (assuming jsonObject is holding the json data):

jsonObject["restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts"]["101010-BPD Bali-Permata ALTO"]["beneAcctNumber"]

Answer (score 0):

restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts has objects inside and this is not an array so index can not be used to get value. "101010-BPD Bali-Permata ALTO" behaves as a property restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts. i am not sure if "101010-BPD Bali-Permata ALTO" is valid property name. ideally this should not contain spaces in between. if this works then try

> restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts["101010-BPD Bali-Permata ALTO"].beneAcctNumber

Answer (score 0):

```
var da = {
"restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts": {
        "101010-BPD Bali-Permata ALTO": {
            "beneficiaryNote": null,
            "beneficiaryName": "Permata ALTO",
            "accountCurrency": "IDR",
            "paymentType": null,
            "beneficiaryIdType": null,
            "transferLimit": null,
            "beneficiaryResident": null,
            "accountLimit": 5.0E7,
            "bankName": "BPD Bali",
            "lastModTime": null,
            "ibInterAcctRef": null,
            "bankCode": "000129",
            "beneficiaryEmail": null,
            "ibInterAcctStrcol1": null,
            "ibInterAcctStrcol2": null,
            "userId": 1551,
            "beneAcctNumber": "101010",
            "beneficiaryId": null,
            "mobileNumber": null
        }
}, "somethingelse" : "whatever"
};
```

To access property (here `beneAcctNumber`) we will use

```
da.restFilteredInterRegisteredAccounts['101010-BPD Bali-Permata ALTO'].beneAcctNumber
```

[`Working Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/3r2t53yh/)